# XML UTF-8 encoding, from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, xml, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a php script that connects to a MySQL server and sends data to the client via xml (ajax). When i open my webpage I see in firebug that the xml is encoded as UTF-8 and it works. But when I add the character ø to a field in the db the client doesn't show any of the data, and according to firebug:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Nothing else is changed except changing one character in one field in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this! I was previously using the old "mysql" api, but changing to "mysqli" and setting `mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");` in my php file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I myself did not write that line, php is making the xml file and sending it back to the client. In the php file I have tihs line: `$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");` , but the xml encoding is changing when I add "ø" to the database.